# Woocommerce Product Listing Name Column is Hidden by default

Tags: woocommerce, product

I'm having a weird issue. For some reason the Name column in Product Listing is showing as Hidden

```
<th scope="col" id='name' class='manage-column column-name hidden column-primary sortable desc'><a href="http://www.someclient.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product&#038;orderby=title&#038;order=asc"><span>Name</span><span class="sorting-indicator"></span></a></th>
```

How can I Show the column by default instead of being hidden.

Please help

Comment: i got the solution for this, i tried various stuff, reinstalling wordpress, deactivating plugins/themes and then activating it again, but none worked for some reason I don't know and couldn't find anything on google too.So then after 8 hours of struggle with the wordpress code I edited a file called class-wp-list-table.php and in that I edited the line number 1077 which was like this

Comment: if ( in_array( $column_key, $hidden ) ) {
    if ($column_key != "name" && $column_key != "thumb"  && $column_key != "cb") {
    $class[] = 'hidden';
    }
   }

Comment: and line no. 1276 as    if ( in_array( $column_name, $hidden ) ) {
    if ($column_name!="name") {
    $classes .= ' hidden';
    }
   }